# React hooks state variable not updating after rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the following example I have an array of element (fruits) that I want to update and use the updated array to perform other operations (in this specific case saving the updated list). My understanding was on re rerender the state will update...but it does not here..or there is a delay between state updating and my action.

In the `addFruit` function I can see 'Peach' being immediately added but the console from the `saveFruits` function still shows the state `fruit` remains unchanged. How can I have this updated to use immediately. (And I know in this case I can pass `newFruits` variable to `saveFruits` to update but I need `fruits` to be updated for other places as well).

Forgive me because this is my millionth question about react async states but there's something just not clicking for me yet.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function ParentComp() {
    const[fruits, setFruits] = useState(['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Pomegranate', 'Kiwi'])


   const addFruit = () => {
      let newFruits = Object.assign([], fruits)
      newFruits.push('Peach')
      setFruits(newFruits)
      saveFruits()
   }
   
   const saveFruits = () => {
      console.log('API req to save fruits.', fruits)
   }

   return (
    <div>
    { fruits.map( (fruit, key) => <div key={key}>{fruit}</div> ) }
      <button type="button" onClick={addFruit}>Add Peach</button>
    </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComp />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: SetState is done asynchronously. Logging to console will not show the final value in state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not accurate to console.log `fruits` because the reference to `fruits` is still referring to the `fruits` you had before you called `setFruits`.

If we console.log `newFruits`, which has the change, it would be more accurate of what is happening.

EDIT: It's probably better to `useEffect` as what @Atul suggested though.

It sometimes helps to visualize how this is done in old React classes. In old React classes the equivalent of this is this (to some degree not actually but close enough to illustrate the point) (Read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

```js
class ParentComp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      fruits: ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Pomegranate', 'Kiwi']
    };
  }

  addFruit = () => {
    let newFruits = Object.assign([], this.state.fruits);
    newFruits.push('Peach')
    this.setFruits(newFruits)
    this.saveFruits();
  }

  setFruits = (fruits) => {
    this.setState({
      fruits
    });
  }

  saveFruits = () => {
    console.log(this.state.fruits);
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
        <div> 
         {this.state.fruits.map((fruit, key) => {
          return (<div key={key}>{fruit}</div>) })} 
          <button type="button" onClick={this.addFruit}>Add Peach</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<ParentComp /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

We get the same problem above but it might be a little clearer. The setState for `fruits` does get called but the console.log happens before the state/render change happens so `this.state.fruits` is still referring to what was in the state before.

I highly recommend reading [React hooks: not magic, just arrays](https://medium.com/@ryardley/react-hooks-not-magic-just-arrays-cd4f1857236e) to get a better sense of what goes on behind the scenes of hooks. It helps explain it a lot.

Answer (score 12):

You can try with useEffect which will give updated state whenever there will be update.

```
useEffect(() => {
    saveFruits();
  }, [fruits]);
```

Comment: What if we call any REST API in `useEffect`?